# Kendo dropdownlist in ajax application

Tags: kendo-ui

I have an ajax application that returns html including a  element. I can give it an id and I am trying to grab it to make it into kendo dropdownlist.

But whatever I try putting the code before or after the ajax result I cannot transform my ajax  element into  a dropdown.

```
$jq(document).ready(function(){
      $jq("#myselect").kendoDropDownList();
});
```

Any ideas how to se this with ajax generated  elements?

Regards

KArel

Comment: Something like this? http://jsbin.com/ocicij/2

Answer (score 0):

remove document.ready event and then add this code  `$jq("#myselect").kendoDropDownList();` 
in the call back function of your intial ajax call where HTML is returned. if still not working, please create a JSFiddle soluction and post the link here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[success](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)** callback of your Ajax request to initialize your 'element'. Also make sure that your 'element' is **input** or **select** html element.